# GCP url map creating path rules for different backend services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, terraform, gcloud

Below is my terraform script. I have set up the necessary forwarding rules and target http proxies. Also the backend services exist. I am able to access all paths under `/images/*`, however, I can’t access the paths under `/videos/*`. From the script, the dafault backend service is `backend-lb-prod` which is the backend service where the path `/images/*` exists. I switched the default backend service to `backend-lb`, I could now access `/videos/*` but not `/images/*`.

```
resource "google_compute_url_map" "url-map-be" {
  name            = "${var.platform_name}-url-map-be-prod"
  default_service = "${google_compute_backend_service.backend-lb-prod.self_link}"

  host_rule {
    hosts        = ["${var.backend_address_name}"]
    path_matcher = "allpaths"
  }

  path_matcher {
    name            = "allpaths"
    default_service = "${google_compute_backend_service.backend-lb-prod.self_link}"

    path_rule {
      paths   = [“/images"]
      service = "${google_compute_backend_service.backend-lb-prod.self_link}"
    }  

    path_rule {
      paths   = [“/images/*"]
      service = "${google_compute_backend_service.backend-lb-prod.self_link}"
    } 

    path_rule {
      paths   = ["/videos"]
      service = "${google_compute_backend_service.backend-lb.self_link}"
    }  

    path_rule {
      paths   = ["/videos/*"]
      service = "${google_compute_backend_service.backend-lb.self_link}"
    }

  }
}
```

When I run the tests for the url map on the google console, this is the error I get

```
Invalid value for field 'resource': ''. Test failure: Expect URL ‘*.*.*.*/videos/go' 
to map to service ‘***93-BACKEND_SERVICE-**-backend-lb', but actually mapped to 
'***93-BACKEND_SERVICE-**-backend-lb-prod’.
```

This is how `google_compute_url_map` in the terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_url_map.html) is illustrated. What am I missing in this case.

**update**

I have included the `/videos` and `/images` paths and the error above is gone. However, from the logs of the application, the traffic is still sent through the default backend service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps any other person. Under the `host_rule` the `hosts` was initially an IP address. I also had it changed to a domain name but it still sent all traffic to the default backend service. I changed it to `*` and it now works as expected. Also to be noted, the paths that are not of the default backend service take a few minutes before they can be accessed.

```
host_rule {
  hosts        = ["*"]
  path_matcher = "allpaths"
}
```